# SQL Combine query on information schema to help build large stored procedures

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to help me build stored procedures faster for tables with many, many columns.

For example, for the update clause in my MERGE statement on a table with 100 columns, I have to do `COLUMN_1 = SOURCE.COLUMN1, COLUMN2...` 100 times, and that's not enjoyable.

I know I can script update/create/etc statements from the object browser, but I'd like to control the formatting a little more.  So:

This query outputs the update format for each column mentoined above:

```
select column_name + ' = SOURCE.' + column_name + ', ' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

*Unfortunately, it does so as multiple results:*

```
COLUMN_1 = SOURCE.COLUMN_1,
COLUMN_2 = SOURCE.COLUMN_2,
etc.
```

---

**The Question:**

Can someone show me how I can modify the query above to **concatenate all of the results** so the output looks more like:

```
COLUMN_1 = SOURCE.COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 = SOURCE.COLUMN_2, etc.
```

**PS:** I know how to use a cursor to cycle through and achieve this result.  I'd like to find a way to do it in a query with a pivot or some T-SQL function for this purpose though if possible.

Comment: Are you thinking of doing this at run-time or just to generate the procedures which that will then be run? I wouldn't advise doing the former...

Comment: @Ben Just to generate procedures to be run.  We have hundreds of thousands of line of T-SQL on our project, so I figure this trick will come in handy in many cases even aside from the example I noted :)

Comment: You just need add FOR XML PATH('') at the end of your query

Comment: @EricZ it worked.  Add that as an answer :)

Comment: Before you get too excited about "for xml path('')", you might see what it does to special characters such as carriage returns, '<', and '>'.  I would just drop he results into Excel and format them there.

Comment: My column names shouldn't contain any special characters, so it's good enough for this use case at least.  Thanks for the heads up though, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as EricZ said you need add FOR XML PATH('') in the end

if you you want the output will be varchar  and not xml use casting

```
select cast((select column_name + ' = SOURCE.' + column_name + ', ' 
             from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
             where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
             FOR XML PATH(''))  
       as varchar)
```

you can also use variables

```
declare @str varchar(8000) = ''  

select @str += column_name + ' = SOURCE.' + column_name + ', ' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'

set @str = left(@str,len(@str))
```